# Axios POST and GET

Tags: reactjs, axios

Quick question: Can you use Axios post and Axios get in the same function/ component? I have been reading the literature but it doesn't say much about using these in combination with one another. My goal is to send data to the database and then retrieve it all within one function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

```
async function sendAndGetData(dataToSent) {
   const postResponse = await axios.post("/myurl", dataToSent)

   // Notice the destructuring { data }
   const { data } = await axios.get("/myurl")

   // You can do whatever you want with "data"

   return data
}
```

Hope this helps!